# How not to match the first empty string in this regex?

Tags: java, regex

(**Disclaimer**: the title of this question is probably too generic and not helpful to future readers having the same issue. Probably, it's just because I can't phrase it properly that I've not been able to find anything yet to solve my issue... I engage in modifying the title, or just close the question once someone will have helped me to figure out what the real problem is :) ).

### High level description

I receive a string in input that contains two information of my interest:

- A version name, which is `3.1.build` and something else later
- A build id, which is `somenumbers-somenumbers-eitherwordsornumbers-somenumbers`

I need to extract them separately.

### More details about the inputs

I have an input which may come in 4 different ways:

**Sample 1**: `v3.1.build.dev.12345.team                  12345-12345-cici-12345` (the spaces in between are some `\t` first, and some whitespaces then).

**Sample 2**: `v3.1.build.dev.12345.team               12345-12345-12345-12345` (this is very similar than the first example, except that in the second part, we only have numbers and `-`, no alphabetic characters).

**Sample 3**:

```
v3.1.build.dev.12345.team
12345-12345-cici-12345
```

(the above is very similar to sample 1, except that instead of `\t` and whitespaces, there's just a new line.

**Sample 4**:

```
v3.1.build.dev.12345.team
12345-12345-12345-12345
```

(same than above, with only digits and dashes in the second line).

Please note that in sample 3 and sample 4, there are some trailing spaces after both strings (not visible here).

To sum up, these are the 4 possible inputs:

```
    String str1 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team\t\t\t\t\t  12345-12345-cici-12345";
    String str2 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team\t\t\t\t\t  12345-12345-12345-12345";
    String str3 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team   \n12345-12345-cici-12345   ";
    String str4 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team   \n12345-12345-12345-12345   ";
```

### My code currently

I have written the following code to extract the information I need (here reporting only relevant, please visit the [fiddle link](https://repl.it/repls/LightcoralWhitesmokeQuark) to have a complete and runnable example):

```
    String versionPattern = "^.+[\\s]";
    String buildIdPattern = "[\\s].+";

    Pattern pVersion = Pattern.compile(versionPattern);
    Pattern pBuildId = Pattern.compile(buildIdPattern);

    for (String str : possibilities) {
        Matcher mVersion = pVersion.matcher(str);
        Matcher mBuildId = pBuildId.matcher(str);
        while(mVersion.find()) {
            System.out.println("Version found: \"" +  mVersion.group(0).replaceAll("\\s", "") + "\"");
        }
        while (mBuildId.find()) {
            System.out.println("Build-id found: \"" +  mBuildId.group(0).replaceAll("\\s", "") + "\"");
        }
    }
```

### The issue I'm facing

The above code works, pretty much. However, in the Sample 3 and Sample 4 (those where the build-id is separated by the version with a `\n`), I'm getting two matches: the first, is just a `""`, the second is the one I wish.

I don't feel this code is stable, and I think I'm doing something wrong with the regex pattern to match the build-id:

```
    String buildIdPattern = "[\\s].+";
```

Does anyone have some ideas in order to exclude the first empty match on the build-id for sample 3 and 4, while keeping all the other matches?
Or some better way to write the regexs themselves (I'm open to improvements, not a big expert of regex)?

Comment: Why not trim string and then split it on one or more whitespaces? Something like `String[] arr = data.trim().split("\\s+");`, this way in `arr[0]` you will have version and in `arr[1]` build info.

Comment: @Pshemo I agree that's a better method.

Comment: @Pshemo out of all the answers, your comment is my favorite one. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description it looks like your data is in form

```
NonWhiteSpaces whiteSpaces NonWhiteSpaces (optionalWhiteSpaces)
```

and you want to get only `NonWhiteSpaces` parts.

This can be achieved in numerous ways. One of them would be to `trim()` your string to get rid of potential trailing whitespaces and then `split` on the whitespaces (there should now only be in the middle of string). Something like

```
String[] arr = data.trim().split("\\s+");// \s also represents line separators like \n \r
String version = arr[0];
String buildID = arr[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`(^v\w.+)\s+(\d+-\d+-\w+-\d+)\s*`

It will capture 2 groups. One will capture the first section (v3.1.build.dev.12345.team), the second gets the last section (12345-12345-cici-12345)

It breaks down like: `(^v\w.+)` ensures that the string starts with a v, then captures all characters that are a number or letter (stopping on white space tabs etc.) `\s+` matches any white space or tabs/newlines etc. as many times as it can. `(\d+-\d+-\w+-\d+)` this reads it in, ensuring that it conforms to your specified formatting. Note that this will still read in the dashes, making it easier for you to split the string after to get the information you need. If you want you could even make these their own capture groups making it even easier to get your info.

Then it ends with `\s*` just to make sure it doesn't get messed up by trailing white space. It uses `*` instead of `+` because we don't want it to break if there's no trailing white space.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be strong for production (aside from the fact that the strings cannot begin with any white-space - which is fixable, but I wasn't sure if it's what you're going for).

```
public class Other {

    static String patternStr = "^([\\S]{1,})([\\s]{1,})(.*)";

    static String str1 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team\t\t\t\t\t  12345-12345-cici-12345";
    static String str2 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team\t\t\t\t\t  12345-12345-12345-12345";
    static String str3 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team   \n12345-12345-cici-12345   ";
    static String str4 = "v3.1.build.dev.12345.team   \n12345-12345-12345-12345   ";

    static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> possibilities = Arrays.asList(str1, str2, str3, str4);

        for (String str : possibilities) {

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Version found:  \"" +  matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\s", "") + "\"");

                System.out.println("Some whitespace found: \"" +  matcher.group(2).replaceAll("\\s", "") + "\"");

                System.out.println("Build-id found: \"" +  matcher.group(3).replaceAll("\\s", "") + "\"");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Pattern NOT found");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Imo, it looks very similar to your original code. In case the regex doesn't look familiar to you, I'll explain what's going on.

Capital S in `[\\S]` basically means match everything except for `[\\s]`. `.+` worked well in your case, but all it is really saying is match anything that isn't empty - even a whitespace. This is not necessarily bad, but would be troublesome if you ever had to modify the regex.

`{1,}` simple means `one or more occurrences`. `{1,2}`, to give another example, would be 1 or 2 occurrences. FYI, `+` usually means 0 or 1 occurrences (maybe not in Java) and `*` means one or more occurrences.

The parentheses denote groups. The entire match is group 0. When you add parentheses, the order from left to right represent group 1 .. group N. So what I did was combine your patterns using groups, separated by one or more occurrences of whitespace. `(.*)` is used for group 2, since that group can have both whitespace and non-whitespace, as long as it doesn't begin with whitespace.

If you have any questions feel free to ask. For the record, your current code is fine if you just add '+' to the buildId pattern: `[\\s]+.+`.

Without that, your regex is saying: `match the whitespace that is followed by no characters or a single character`. Since all of your whitespace is followed by more whitespace, you matching just a single whitespace.

Comment: Note another good solution would be to use positive/negative lookahead/lookbehind. I doubt Java supports this tbh, but in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

Use the pattern `^(v\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)`, where the capture-groups capture the *version* and *build* respectively, here's the complete snippet:

```
String unitPattern ="^(v\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(unitPattern);

    for (String str : possibilities) {
        System.out.println("Analyzing \"" + str + "\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);


        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Version found: \"" +  matcher.group(1) + "\"");
            System.out.println("Build-id found: \"" +  matcher.group(2) + "\"");
        }

    }
```

[Fiddle to try it.](https://repl.it/repls/CooperativeElasticMicrostation)

## Nitty Gritties

**Reason for the empty lines in the output**

It's because of how the `Matcher` class interprets the `.`; The `.` **DOES NOT** match newlines, it stops matching just before the `\n`. For that you need to add the flag [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) using `Pattern.compile(String pattern, int flags)`.

**An attempt**

But even with `Pattern.DOTALL`, you'll still not be able to match, because of the way you have defined the pattern. A better approach is to match the full *build* and *version* as a **unit** and then extract the necessary parts.

`^(v\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)`

This does trick where :

- `^(v\\S+)` defines the starting of the unit and also captures version information
- `\\s+` matches the tabs, new line, spaces etc
- `(\\S+)` captures the final contiguous build id